# Объединить синонимичные метки {"config", "configuration"}

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Объединить:

- [config](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/config) - 93 вопроса;
- [configuration](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/configuration) - 41 вопрос.

Эти метки нужно объединить, так как ими уже отмечены примерно соразмерные параллельные множества вопросов.

Вероятнее всего слияние следует произвести в новую метку [конфигурация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Comment: О какой конфигурации речь?

Comment: @älёxölüt Вероятно речь о конфигурационных файлах.

Comment: Занятно. На en SO - это разные вещи если смотреть на описание https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/config https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/configuration (:

Comment: Можно ответы-вопросники сделать, чтоб люди проголосовали. Но, по-моему, создавать [tag:конфигурация] нет смысла, раз её не используют. И нужно синонимизировать к [tag:configuration].